# Is this conditional regex the most efficient?

Tags: php, regex, conditional-statements

I'll give my example in PHP. I am testing if quoted strings are properly closed (e.g., quoted string must close with double quotes if begins with dq). There must be at least 1 char between the quotes, and that char-set between the quotes cannot include the same start/end quote character. For example:

```
$myString = "hello";// 'hello' also good but "hello' should fail

if (preg_match("/^(\")?[^\"]+(?(1)\")|(\')?[^\']+(?(1)\')$/", $myString)) {
    die('1');
} else {
    die('2');
}

// The string '1' is outputted which is correct
```

I am new to conditional regex but to me it seems that I cannot make the preg_match() any simpler. Is this correct?

Comment: Efficient or simpler? What about escape sequences (escaped double quote inside doubles quoted strings)?

Comment: so, this string `$str = "hello, I said: \"How are you?\"";` would be invalid in your case?

Comment: You need to put everything between start and end anchor in a (non-capturing) group, otherwise those anchors are part of the alternation

Comment: wait sorry...escaped inner quotes ok...my bad

Comment: Can you provide an example of more strings? Maybe `('|")([^\1]+?)\1`?

Comment: quoted string can be literally anything but should have 1 char between quotes

Comment: I don't want to write 2 preg_match() - 1 for the single quotes and 1 for the dq

Comment: I don't think using a conditional is the good way here

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob, if one of the answers helped you, please select and/or upvote it.

Comment: @BeetleJuice deleted that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that, there's no need to use the "conditional feature". But you need to check the string from the start until the end *(in other word, you can't do it only checking a part of the string)*:

```
preg_match('~\A[^"\']*+(?:"[^"\\\\]*+(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*+"[^"\']*|\'[^\'\\\\]*+(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*+\'[^"\']*)*+\z~s', $str)
```

If you absolutely want at least one character inside quotes, you need to add these lookaheads `(?=[^"])` and `(?=[^'])`:

```
preg_match('~\A[^"\']*+(?:"(?=[^"])[^"\\\\]*+(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*+"[^"\']*|\'(?=[^\'])[^\'\\\\]*+(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*)*+\'[^"\']*)*+\z~s', $str)
```

details:

```
~
\A  # start of the string
[^"']*+ #"# all that is not a quote
(?:
    " #"# opening quote
    (?=[^"]) #"# at least one character that isn't a quote
    [^"\\]*+ #"# all characters that are not quotes or backslashes
    (?:\\.[^"\\]*)*+ #"# an escaped character and the same (zero or more times)
    " #"# closing quote
    [^"']*  
  | #"# or same thing for single quotes
    '(?=[^'])[^'\\]*+(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*+'[^"']*
)*+
\z  # end of the string
~s  # singleline mode: the dot matches newlines too
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/dY1tR0/1)

Note that these patterns are designed to deal with escaped characters.

Most of the time a conditional can be replaced with a simple alternation.

As an aside: don't believe that shorter patterns are always better than longer patterns, it's a false idea.

Comment: I would have never come up with this at this point. I had an alternative but needed to get the last char using substring($myString, -1)  (or first char as $myString[0]) to set the matching quote in the regex

Comment: Why not start the pattern with ^? Why is \A necessary?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob: using `\A` and `\z` is more explicit than `^` and `$` since the meaning doesn't change whatever the mode (multiline or not) first and because `$` can match the end of the string **or** the position before the last character when the string ends with a newline. `\z` always matches the end of the string  and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the two observations below, I built my regex to be simple and fast, but to *not* deal with escaped quotes

- The OP was asked specifically whether the string `$str = "hello, I
  said: \"How are you?\""` would be invalid and did not respond
- The OP mentioned performance (efficiency as a criterion)

I'm also not a fan of code that is tough to read, so I used the `<<<` [Nowdoc notation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) to avoid having to escape anything in the regex pattern

My solution:

```
$strings = [
    "'hello's the word'",
    "'hello is the word'",
    '"hello "there" he said"',
    '"hello there he said"',
    '"Hi',
    "'hello",
    "no quotes",
    "''"
];
$regexp = <<< 'TEXT'
/^('|")(?:(?!\1).)+\1$/
TEXT;
foreach ($strings as $string):
    echo "$string - ".(preg_match($regexp,$string)?'true':'false')."<br/>";
endforeach;
```

Output:

```
'hello's the word' - false
'hello is the word' - true
"hello "there" he said" - false
"hello there he said" - true
"Hi - false
'hello - false
no quotes - false
'' - false
```

How it works:

```
^('|")   //starts with single or double-quote
(?:      //non-capturing group
  (?!\1) //next char is not the same as first single/double quote
  .      //advance one character
)+       //repeat group with next char (there must be at least one char)
\1$      //End with the same single or double-quote that started the string
```